# How to add on click a li element to another container and rest of li stay fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a litle problem:

I have this list:

```
<ul id="nextlevel">
<li class="listadetalii"><a style="width:100%;color:red;font-weight:600;cursor:pointer" rel="03.Accessories" data-folder="01.Hi tech (028_003)" data-titlu="Hi tech" id="01.Cosuri si cuiere" class="red-gros singlelink folder">Hi tech<p style="width:100%;color:#828282;font-size:70%" class="muted">Luni, 18 Mar 2013 16:07:14</p></a>

    <ul class="detalii-produs hide">
        <li class="togo">Image 1</li>
        <li class="detalii-produs-lista dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" style="float:right;margin-right:15px;width:100%;font-size:12px;" class="pull-right">Fișă produs</a>

        </li>
        <li class="detalii-produs-lista dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" style="float:right;margin-right:15px;width:100%;font-size:12px;" class="pull-right">Listă prețuri</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="listadetalii"><a style="width:100%;color:red;font-weight:600;cursor:pointer" rel="03.Accessories" data-folder="02.Net (028_002)" data-titlu="Net" id="01.Cosuri si cuiere" class="red-gros singlelink folder">Net<p style="width:100%;color:#828282;font-size:70%" class="muted">Marti, 16 Apr 2013 09:53:43</p></a>

    <ul class="detalii-produs hide">
        <li class="togo">Image 2</li>
        <li class="detalii-produs-lista dropdown-submenu"><a href="" style="float:right;margin-right:15px;width:100%;font-size:12px;" class="pull-right">Fișă produs</a>

        </li>
        <li class="detalii-produs-lista dropdown-submenu"><a href="" style="float:right;margin-right:15px;width:100%;font-size:12px;" class="pull-right">Listă prețuri</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="listadetalii "><a style="width: 100%; color: red; font-weight: 600; cursor: pointer; outline: medium none;" rel="03.Accessories" data-folder="03.)" data-titlu="Cuiere" id="01.Cosuri si cuiere" class="red-gros singlelink folder">Cuiere<p style="width:100%;color:#828282;font-size:70%" class="muted">Luni, 18 Mar 2013 10:53:47</p></a>

    <ul class="detalii-produs hide" style="display: none;">
        <li class="togo">Image 3</li>
        <li class="detalii-produs-lista dropdown-submenu"><a href="" style="float:right;margin-right:15px;width:100%;font-size:12px;" class="pull-right">Fișă produs</a>

        </li>
        <li class="detalii-produs-lista dropdown-submenu"><a href="" style="float:right;margin-right:15px;width:100%;font-size:12px;" class="pull-right">Listă prețuri</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This list is collapsed. When i click on **"Hi tech"** a next list is expanded and the content is visible.
I want the content of the li element class togo  to go on div alfa and hide li and the rest of li-s stay on this list.

Same behavior for the rest of elements Net, Cuiere...

```
<div id="alfa">here must be Image (n)</div>
```

More detalied code on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gxg1974/Jy3EK/

Thank you all for tips and guidance.

Comment: bit hard to understand will you make it more clear for us.I want the content of the li element class togo to go on div alfa and hide li and the rest of li-s stay on this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what i understand is, you want the content of `togo` to be in `div#alfa`. So here's how to do it..

```
$('ul#nextlevel a.singlelink').on("click", function () {
    $(this).css('outline', 'none');
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
        
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('slow', function () {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
        });
    } else {
        var img = $(this).siblings('ul').children("li.togo").hide()
        .html();
        console.log(img);
        
        $("#alfa").html(img);
        $('ul#nextlevel li.current ul').slideUp('slow', function () {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
        });
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
        });

    }
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WTwXq/3/)

**UPDATE**

I've used `.on` instead of live as `.live()` is deprecated.

If there's something more, let me know.

Comment: on my script ".on" doesn't work, i use ".live" . i addapted your answer to my script and work. Thank you.

Comment: glad to hear that. :D And you might be using old version of jQuery since `.live()` got deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and was removed from 1.9.

Comment: jQuery 1.8.3 is in this application

Comment: yes.. and if, in future you update jquery lib to greater than 1.9 , `.live()` won't work.